# Clear contents of a locked file in windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Need to clear the contents of a log file(s) which is(are) locked by a process already from command prompt. 
When I tried doing

> echo "" > filename

I get a error saying, the file is locked by a process.

I couldn't even open the file in notepad, clear contents and save.

Currently I'm opening the file in notepad++ and quickly pressing CTRL + a,CTRL+x,CTRL+s :)

Is there a way to get this done from cmd? How is notepad++ able to handle edit and save while notepad is not able to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a program like Unlocker to release the lock:
http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Answer (score 5):

I found the best solution for me is
Powershell> Clear-Content filename.log
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156808.aspx

> The `Clear-Content` cmdlet enables you to erase the contents of a file without deleting the file itself. For example, suppose you run this command:
>
> `Clear-Content c:\scripts\test.txt`
>
> When you execute that command the file Test.txt will still be in the folder C:\Scripts; there just won’t be any data of any kind in the file.
>
> Wildcard characters can be used with Clear-Content. This command erases the contents of any file in C:\Scripts whose file name starts with the letter E:
>
> `Clear-Content c:\scripts\e*`
>
> You are not limited to erasing only text files. The following command deletes all the data in an Excel spreadsheet:
>
> `Clear-Content c:\scripts\test.xls`
>
> And this command erases the contents of the Word document C:\Scripts\Test.doc:
>
> `Clear-Content c:\scripts\test.doc`

Comment: Are you sure this works with locked files?

Answer (score 2):

Locked files cannot be deleted, but they can be renamed. It could be that Notepad++ is using "safe saves" – creating a temporary file with the new contents, then quickly deleting the original (this step probably fails) and renaming temporary file to the original name.